# Creating a plist to access a variable and rewriting it

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables, int, plist

Is it possible to create a plist to hold one variable  integer called CurrentQuestion which can be altered.
This variables value will be constantly changed by various different classes which can access the new value of the currentQuestion.
I seem to be having a problem transferring the value of variables using the prepareForSegue function and think this option may be the best option.

Comment: Yes this is possible to add, read, update same plist file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use NSUserDefaults to store this.

```
// setting logic
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"CurrentQuestion"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

// retrieval logic
NSInteger currentQuestion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"CurrentQuestion"];
```

It will persist between application launches as well so take that into consideration.

Comment: Is this how to access it in a plist

Comment: Plist and userdefaults are two different things

Comment: For your requirements, user defaults would be a better solution rather than performing file i/o in order to maintain a single application-wide Integer.

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Ben one or two quesitions. will this alter the value of currentQuestion across all classes & where is the best place to put the above code

Comment: Yes the values you put in NSUserDefaults are global to your app. The code I've provided demonstrates how to store an Integer for the key CurrentQuestion and how to retrieve it. Just put it wherever you need to do those things.